# How keywords inherit to default arguments

Tags: python, functools

We know a partial function is an original function for particular argument values. Basic syntax of partial function is,

```
partial(func[, *args][, **keywords])
```

Now, let's assume a particular program.

```
from functools import partial

def power(a, b):
    return a ** b
pw = partial(power, b=4)
print('Default keywords for pw :', pw.keywords)
print('Default arguments for pw :', pw.args)
print('Answer of pw is: ',pw(3))

# Output
# -------
# Default keywords for pw: {'b': 4}
# Default arguments for pw: ()
# Answer of pw is:  81
```

The output is correct and the above partial function i set keywords as `b=4` and default `agrs` is `()`. Now, if I omit the keyword `b` and that place i put only 4. The scenario is changed to answer is 64.

```
partial(power, 4)

# Output
# -------
# Default keywords for pw: {}
# Default arguments for pw: (4,)
# Answer of pw is:  64
```

My question is why args and keywords get interchanged when I don't want to pass `b` since though in the first case I didn't pass `a` but the result was correct.

Comment: What would you expect your 4 to be attributed to, if not the first parameter, which is `a`?

Comment: 4**3=64. I don;t see anything strange there. without positioning, partial will assign the default parameters sequentially so 4 goes to 'a' and the result function takes further parameters for b

Comment: Strictly speaking, an *instance* of the class `partial` is a wrapper around both a function and zero or more arguments to be passed to the function when the `partial` instance is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing `4` as a *positional* argument, and those are applied strictly from left to right when calling the `partial` instance. That is, `partial(f, 4)` is roughly the equivalent of `lambda x: pow(4, x)`. There is no way to define an equivalent of the function `lambda x: pow(x, 4)` with `partial` without using keyword arguments.

Comment: I'm trying to remember where, or if, I saw a third-party package that provided something like `rpartial` that would apply positional arguments from the right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused with the interplay of `partial` and `positional` and `keyword` argument here.

Here is the simple explanations:  when keywords arg. are used in the call, the order in which the  arguments are listed does `NOT` matter!  Python matches by name, not
order. The caller must supply - spam, and eggs in the examples shown next, but they can be matched by position or by name - as you can see last 2 examples.

```py
def func(spam, eggs, toast=0, ham=1): # first 2 required
    print((spam, eggs, toast, ham))


func(1, 2)                  #  (1, 2, 0, 1)
func(1, ham=2, eggs=0)      #  (1, 0, 0, 2)
#        *****
#
print('------------------')
print('spam-lover, hate eggs: ') 
func(spam=2, eggs=0)        #  (2, 0, 0, 1)

print()
print('love spam and eggs: ')
func(toast=1, eggs=4, spam=2) # (2, 4, 1, 1)

print('love spam/eggs and ham, want it toast too! ')
func(ham=6, eggs=4, spam=2, toast=1) # (2, 4, 1, 6)

func(1, 2, 3, 4)             #  (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The form - name=value means different things in the call and the def!!!

1. a keyword in the call and
2. a `default` in the func. header.